# user login not being remembered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

Hi for some reason users are being automatically logged out after a few minutes.

i cant pinpoint how long  - maybe ten minutes. basically if i log in,  close the browser and reopen my site then i am still logged in.  however if i close and come back to it ten minutes later it requires me to re-login.
this is from my web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1440" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

This is executed when a user logs in:

```
  private void CreateAuthTicket(string userName, bool rememberMe, string userData)
     {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
1,userName,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),rememberMe,userData);

         string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
         HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
         Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this local or on a hosted environment? Shared hosting providers sometimes set their lifetime very low to free up resources regularly. If this only occurs when you deploy the site it might be a good idea to check with your provider what their settings are. I once had a hoster which set their lifetime to 5 minutes(!!), which caused similar problems.

Comment: what settings do i need to ask them about?

Comment: Something like session lifetime, or App Pool recycle interval. It's in the advanced settings on an Application Pool in IIS manager if you want to look for it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(rememberMe) {
  faCookie.Expires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)); //or something else here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout setting on session cookies in IIS. It could be that that's causing your session to expire.

By default, the "Remember Me" functionality in MVC should create a persistent cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be disabled in browser, check it too

Answer (score 0):

If changing the cookie period doesn't work for you. You may need to generate a Machine Key for your site. This has solved the Remember Me not working issue in the past.

[Machine key Generator](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/)